# Meaning of TortoiseHG status icons

Tags: icons, tortoisehg

Does anyone have a list of statuses corresponding to the the icons used in the Repository Explorer of TortoiseHg?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TortoiseHg uses the same TortoiseOverlays package as TortoiseSVN and therefore shares the same icons. It's a definite oversight that the TortoiseHG documentation doesn't have a chart listing them all but there is one in the TortoiseSVN documentation:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html#tsvn-dug-general-icons

I was surprised to find that such a description was absent in the TortoiseHG docs. I went ahead and filed an enhancement bug requesting its inclusion in the future.

Good catch Even.

Answer (score 1):

The TortoiseHg docs have a brief description [here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.1/explorer.html), but the TortoiseSVN link that Rakis provided is much better.